# why numeric is data is automatic convering to exponential data while sending data from DB to unix?

Tags: sqlplus

I wrote a script which will fetch data from DB and send it to unix terminal but I am getting proper output in Database but not in UNIX.

DB output:

date        feed_name      type      Request_ID     count      status

1/6/2017 5:20:18 AM MTS_FEDWIRE_CHIPS_TRANSACTION_FEED  MQ  3712075882556   1   SUCCESS

UNIX output:

06-JAN-17 MTS_FEDWIRE_CHIPS_TRANSACTION_FEED       MQ         *3.7067E+12*                          0 SUCCESS

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DataDirectory='/auto/users/scripts'

ORACLE_HOME=/tools/bin/oracle-10.2.0.1-64
export ORACLE_HOME
TNS_ADMIN=${DataDirectory}
export TNS_ADMIN

DBUSER='userid'
DBUSERPASSWORD='passowrd'
DB='dbname'

var=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -S ${DBUSER}/${DBUSERPASSWORD}@${DB} <<EOF
spool /auto/users/scripts/DB_output.txt
set linesize 150;
SET FEED OFF;
SET TERMOUT ON;
SET VERIFY OFF;
SET ECHO ON;
SET HEAD OFF;
SET PAGESIZE 0;
set feedback off
set heading off
select update_time,feed_name,received_mode,request_id,records_processed,status from FEED_REQUEST WHERE FEED_NAME='TRANSACTION_FEED' AND AS_OF=to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy') and ROWNUM=1 ORDER BY 1 DESC;
spool off
exit;
EOF`
```

Could you please help me how I will get proper Request_id in number format please ? Thanks a lot

Comment: `COL number_of_records_processed for 99999999999999999999999999`

Comment: Unix, bash and shell have nothing to do here. I guess the `sqlplus` command must configured properly to print integer numbers. How do you get the `DB output`? A GUI SQL client?

Comment: @ibre5041 - that is correct, but these days there's little need for shorthand; `column` rather than `col` and especially `format` rather than `for` will make the command much easier to read, especially by other developers who will need to maintain your code in the future.

Comment: @Jdamian, Hi Sir, I am getting the DB output via SQL Client only but while printing in unix it is converted to exponential value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to configure the column format in SQL*Plus (see example below).

More importantly, since the `request_id` seems to be meant as an identifier (you are not going to do arithmetic on it, are you?) - why is it declared as NUMBER and not as VARCHAR2(n) where n is large enough to accommodate your id's? If it must only contain digits, that can be enforced easily with constraints.

```
SQL> select 3712075882556 as zzz from dual;

       ZZZ
----------
3.7121E+12

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL> column zzz format 999999999999999
SQL> /

             ZZZ
----------------
   3712075882556

1 row selected.
```

You need to add a similar `column` command in your script, before the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thanks sir for the update. But I tried with below command

select * from(select time,fname,rec_mode,column request_id for 9(15),num_records,status 
from REQUEST WHERE F_NAME='STS_FEED' AND AS_OF=to_char(SYSDATE-2, 'dd-mon-yyyy') 
ORDER BY time DESC) where ROWNUM=1;
But I am  ora-00936 missing expression, I don't know wheather I can directly put "column request_id for 9(15)" in the select statement.
DBop: 1/6/2017 3:34:31 PM STS_FEED MQ 3715081266052 20 SUCCESS
Unixop: 06-JAN-17 STS_FEED  MQ   3.7151E+12  20 SUCCESS  (DATE timestamp is missing)
could you please help me on this please ?

Comment: `COLUMN` is a SQL\*Plus command, it is not a SQL command. Oracle does not understand the `COLUMN` command. You need to add it to the "preamble" in your script, after the SET commands but not in the `SELECT` command. It should be on a line by itself. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve013.htm#SQPUG034

Comment: Thanks Sir, It is working for me and again highly appreciate your valuable time.